# How node-scheduler working in this scenerio

Tags: node.js, scheduler

I am new in NodeJs and now I want to use node-scheduler, but i have just one query, please give me suggestion regarding this.

```
https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule

When I setup a scheduler that run in every 5 Minutes, If the scheduler does 
not completed within 5 minutes. So my question is that then the scheduler 
will start another thread or not?
```

Please solve my query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since jobs don't seem to have a mechanism to let the scheduler know they are done, jobs will be scheduled according to their scheduled time alone.

In other words: if you schedule a job to run every 5 minutes, it will be started every 5 minutes, even if the job itself takes more than 5 minutes to complete.

To clarify: this doesn't start a new thread for each job, as JS is single-threaded. If a job blocks the event loop (for instance by doing heavy calculations), it *is* possible for the scheduler to not be able to start a new job when its time has arrived, but blocking the event loop is not a good thing.

Comment: @robertkpel, Thanks for your answer. Means a new thread run for the same scheduled job.

Comment: @UmeshSehta I edited my answer to clarify that it doesn't mean jobs get run in threads.